# Interactive regex find highliting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How can I make Notepad++ highlight my regex matches as I type?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a plugin that does inline, as-you-type highlighting of regex matches. But you could give RegEx Helper a try:
http://nppregexhelper.sourceforge.net/